# How to check if a value of an array is empty

Tags: vb6

I am writing a chess program and has to see whether certain value are empty. I tried

`aPiece` is an array of `CommandButtons`. `cmdSquare` is a control array of shapes.

```
Private aPiece(63) As CommandButton

...

For p = 0 To 63
    If IsEmpty(aPiece(p)) Then
        aPiece(p).Left = cmdSquare(p).Left
        aPiece(p).Top = cmdSquare(p).Top
    
    End If
Next p
```

All variable are declared and is seem to be IsEmpty function which is not working.

Comment: IsEmpty only returns meaningful information for variants.  How is aPiece declared?  What does it contain?

Comment: It contains command buttons in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IsEmpty` method only returns meaningful information for variants.  Since the array contains objects, you need to check like this:

```
If aPiece(p) Is Nothing Then
```

However, this seems like only part of the answer.  The above logic is saying "If there is no piece in my array then update it's location".  That doesn't make sense to me and will generate an error.  You also need to add `Not` like below:

```
For p = 0 To 1
   If Not aPiece(p) Is Nothing Then
      aPiece(p).Left = cmdSquare(p).Left
      aPiece(p).Top = cmdSquare(p).Top
   End If
Next p
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants to know if a square on his chessboard is empty, that is, contains no chess piece, and is misinterpreting what the `IsEmpty` function is for.

Comment: Yes, it is unclear what the OP is intending in context.  But the first code snippet answers the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the datatype of `aPiece`. If it is a variant and you haven't assigned a value to it, `IsEmpty` will return true. However, if it is a `String`, `Date`, `Integer`, etc. those are automatically initialized (`String` will be an empty string, `Integer` will be 0) so `IsEmpty` will return false.

A pretty good reference is this page: [IsEmpty Function - Visual Basic 6.0](https://chennaiiq.com/developers/reference/visual_basic/functions/isempty.asp)

Comment: The aPiece is an array of CommadButtons is is declared 
as. 
Private aPiece(63) As CommandButton